# error 419 page expired when trying to redirect users based on their role in the login page

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to redirect users based on their user role in the table

```
public function redirectTo()
{
  $auth = Auth::user()->type;
  switch ($auth) 
  {
    case 'default':
      return redirect()->route('user');
      break;
    case 'admin':
      return redirect()->route('admin');
      break;
    default;
      return redirect()->route('user');
      break;
  }
}
```

but I keep getting 419 page expired error.

Comment: `redirectTo` is supposed to return a string, the path to redirect to .. assuming you are talking about this method on a `LoginController`? also the redirect path is a fallback, it will try to redirect you to the intended URL first ... and  `default;`?

Comment: Does this happen when you try to login user? Error 419 or Page Expired may occur when we do not include CSRF_TOKEN form input in the page HTML body.            Have you included @csrf token?

Comment: yes but it was working without the redirect function @Xhuljo it was after i tried to redirect user to their role in the app that the error occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public function redirectTo()
    {
        $auth = Auth::user()->type;

        if($auth == "default"){
          return '/user';
        }else if($auth == "admin"){
          return '/admin'
        }else{
          return '/user';
        }
    }
```

**Or if you use switch case**

```
public function redirectTo()
{
  $auth = Auth::user()->type;
  switch ($auth) 
  {
    case 'default':
      return '/user';
      break;
    case 'admin':
       return '/admin'
      break;
    default;
      return '/user';
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: once time i have same issue switch case not working in my code so i used just if else so its workerd for me so i suggest you thank you!! Happy coding..

Comment: i'm getting this error now **ErrorException
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected**

Comment: return url not route

Comment: `if($auth == "default"){
          return '/user';
        }else if($auth == "admin"){
          return '/admin'
        }else{
          return '/user';
        }`